# iOS 8 Popover controller wont dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have a trio of functions and a property that I use to control my popovers as follows:

```
-(void)dismissPopoverIfPresentAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.currentPopover)
    {
        [self.currentPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:animated];
        self.currentPopover = nil;
    }
}

-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController inView:(UIView *)view fromRect:(CGRect)rect suppressArrow:(BOOL)suppressArrow
{
//Did the user just tap on a button to bring up the same controller that's already displayed?
//If so, just dismiss the current controller.
BOOL closeOnly = NO;

if (self.currentPopover)
{
    UIViewController *currentController = [self.currentPopover.contentViewController isKindOfClass:UINavigationController.class] ? ((UINavigationController *)self.currentPopover.contentViewController).topViewController : self.currentPopover.contentViewController;
    UIViewController *newController = [viewController isKindOfClass:UINavigationController.class] ? ((UINavigationController *)viewController).topViewController : viewController;
    if ([currentController isKindOfClass:newController.class])
        closeOnly = YES;

    [self dismissPopoverIfPresentAnimated:NO];

}

if (!closeOnly)
    {
        self.currentPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
        self.currentPopover.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.currentPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:view permittedArrowDirections:(suppressArrow ? 0 : UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

- (instancetype) initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
  {
  self = [super initWithContentViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init]];
  if (self)
  {
      UIViewController* contentViewController = super.contentViewController;
      [contentViewController addChildViewController:viewController];
      [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:contentViewController];
      [contentViewController.view addSubview:viewController.view];

  ```
  [self setPopoverContentSize:viewController.preferredContentSize animated:NO];
  ```

  }
  return self;
  }

This runs fine in iOS 7, but in iOS 8 the problem is there is a delay between the call to presentPopoverFromRect and when the item actually shows up onscreen. So, if a user double taps a button to show a popover, the first tap will properly dismiss, then "start" the showing of the new controller.  The second tap will make the dismiss call (the popover is not yet visible) and then not show the new controller (this is a design feature so that click a button will show a popover, clicking it again will hide it).
The problem is that the call to dismiss the popover doesn't actually work and the popover will show up.  At that point I can't get rid of it because my property is nil and I think it is not showing.

My guess is this is an iOS 8 bug where the dismiss somehow doesn't see a visible popover and thus doesn't do anything, where instead, it should prevent it from showing up.

Oh, one last note is that the call to presentViewController is always done on the main thread.

Comment: Do you setContentViewController? I get the same problem. So I do next. I initialize uipopovercontroller with uiviewcontroller and set content view controller on it as child view controller

Comment: Sorry, yes I missed that that function was ours when I initially posted.  I have updated the post to include it, thanks.

Comment: you seems trying to dismiss popOverController that is not yet in view, ask if it is visible if([self.currentPopover isPopoverVisible]){
        
        [self.currentPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.currentPopover = nil;
    }

Comment: The `currentPopover` have a `Strong` reference?